# Html getting cut off after appenTo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am newer to programming and Javascript/JQuery so please any help is appreciated. 
I'm working on a manager for addresses for our companies new WebApplication. I'm using a WebApi to make some AJAX calls and fill in data for each "MailStop" inside of a location in the location manager of my application. A MailStop just helps someone find a spot inside of an address...

```
            555 Cleveland Ave NW
            Apt. 3
mailstop => Upstairs, Kevin's Desk
            Canton, Ohio 44718
```

So, at each location you can have as many MailStops as you need. Although, clients hardly ever use more than a few.

I have everything I need almost working for this problem but when I use $.appendTo() something is going wrong.

[image: wat]

As you can see from above the elements are getting appended properly but they are not displaying. In my code I am trying to use .scrollHeight to increase the height of the panel but no matter how many mailStop elements are getting inserted the .scrollHeight is always 32px. I need to find a way to increase the panel by about 100px for every mailstop. Below is my code...

```
function getAjax(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url
    });
}

function displayResults(data, addTo) {

    $.each(data, function (k, v) {
        $('<div class="mailStops">' +
            `<input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="${v.MailStop1}" />` +
            `<input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="${v.MailStop2}" />` +
            `<button class="btn btn-danger btn-block DeleteMailStop" value="${v.MailStopID}">Delete</button>` +
            '</div >').appendTo(addTo);
    });

}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("btnMailStop");
var i;


for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {

    acc[i].onclick = function () {

        var LocId = this.value;
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        //var panel = $("#MailStopPanel" + LocId);
        var panel = document.getElementById("MailStopPanel" + LocId);
        if (panel.style.maxHeight != "0px") {
            //if panel is open remove elements and close it
            var removeStops = document.querySelectorAll(".mailStops");

            $.each(removeStops, function (k, element) {
                panel.removeChild(element);
            })
            panel.style.maxHeight = "0px";

        }
        else {
            //if panel is closed get AJAX data and append it to the panel
            var uri = '/api/MailStop/' + LocId;

            var promise = getAjax(uri);

            promise.then(data => displayResults(data, panel));

            //Need to increase the panel height and window height enough for all elements to be seen
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider using the height property instead of scrollHeight, also, consider letting the height be controlled by the content by having the height be "initial" or "auto" and maybe a max-height or min-height property.

In the general practise, Adding stuff to a div and *also* modifying it's height is usually a bad idea, unless you can calculate precisely how many pixels each thing takes, and each thing has a very precise height.

Answer (score 0):

A few things just needed moved around here. Thank you to Felipe Valdes for getting the gears turning and getting me closer to solution. here's updated Javascript.

```
function getAjax(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url
    });
}

function displayResults(data, addTo, panelID) {

    if (data.length < 1) {
        $('#MailStopPanel' + panelID).css('height', 35 + "px");
    }
    else {
        $('#MailStopPanel' + panelID).css('height', (data.length * 130) + "px");

        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            $('<div class="mailStops">' +
                `<input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="${v.MailStop1}" />` +
                `<input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="${v.MailStop2}" />` +
                `<button class="btn btn-danger btn-block DeleteMailStop" value="${v.MailStopID}">Delete</button>` +
                '</div >').appendTo(addTo);
        });
    }
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("btnMailStop");
var i;


for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {

    acc[i].onclick = function () {

        var LocId = this.value;
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        //var panel = $("#MailStopPanel" + LocId);
        var panel = document.getElementById("MailStopPanel" + LocId);
        if (panel.style.height != "0px") {
            //if panel is open remove elements and close it
            var removeStops = document.querySelectorAll(".mailStops");

            $.each(removeStops, function (k, element) {
                panel.removeChild(element);
            })
            panel.style.height = "0px";

        }
        else {
            //if panel is closed get AJAX data and append it to the panel
            var uri = '/api/MailStop/' + LocId;

            var promise = getAjax(uri);

            promise.then(data => displayResults(data, panel, LocId));
        }
    };
}
```